# Find out the "Open With" menu items in Finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder

How can I replicate the Finder's "Open With" menu for a given file type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
- (NSArray *)applicationsForURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [(NSArray *)LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL((CFURLRef)url,
                                                   kLSRolesAll) autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` could be the basis of a solution.